# Can't display image in HTML

Tags: html, image

Ok.  I can't figure this out.  Here's the HTML:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <img source="sample.jpg" alt="Wheres my image" style="width:100;height:38">
    </body>
</html>
```

Pretty simple. The picture is just a simple block with some text in it. It's 2k in size.  And for some reason I can't attach it here.

Both the image and the HTML are in the same sub directory in my Documents folder (Win10 x64 pro).

When I load the HTML, I just get the text from the "alt" setting for the image.

Browsers I'm testing on:

- Chrome: 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit);
- IE: Version 11.540.15063.0;
- Edge: 40.15063.0.0, EdgeHTML version: 15.15063

Any ideas?

Comment: wrong attr source=   it must be src=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
<img src="sample.jpg" alt="Wheres my image" style="width:100;height:38">
```

You are using `source` insted of `src` that is causing error so change that. I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change "source=" to "src=" other than that it should work.

Look here for more...
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

In your style add a unit to the width and height like 'px'. Then replace attribute `source` to `src` :)

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="sample.jpg" alt="Wheres my image" style="width:100px;height:38px">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.  My age is catching up with me.   :)

Comment: hehe no worries

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have used the attribute `source` instead of **[`src`](http://html.com/attributes/img-src/)** for your **[`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)** tag.

Rewrite your image tag as:

```
<img src="sample.jpg" alt="Wheres my image" style="width:100;height:38">
```

If the image **still** won't load for you, there are three possible reasons why this may be happening:

- You have forgotten to upload the image to the server.
  Check it's actually accessible by manually navigating to it.
- You have referenced the file incorrectly, either by name or by path.
- You need to clear your cache.
  Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and click the refresh icon to clear your image cache.